# Submit textarea press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I have a form with only one `textarea`. I want to submit it, but only press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Default event when on `textarea` press <kbd>Enter</kbd> is going to a new line, and I want to change it.

```
function textSubmit() {
    $("textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        }
        else if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
        //else if (e.keyCode == 18 && e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
        }
    });
}
```

How do I make the form submit when press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of go to a new line?

Answer (score 2):

Use `keydown` instead of `keypress` as `keypress` only triggers when a printable character is being produced:

```js
$("textarea").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.altKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
  } else if(e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parents('form').submit();      
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should handle the alt key:

```js
function textSubmit() {
  $(".textarea").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.altKey === true) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n").focus();
      } else {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
      }
    }
  });
}

textSubmit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

What You are doing wrong is You have not Invoked your function.Either Invoke your function by doing `textSubmit()` or remove that codeBlock inside your function to global environMent.And as @Scott said use 'keyDown' in stead of 'keyPress' as 'keypress' only  relays the character resulting from a keypress, and is only called if there is one.

```
function textSubmit() {
       $("textarea").on("keydown",function(e) {
         if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).val($(this).val() + "\n");
        }
       else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        }
    });
}
textSubmit();
```

Here i Just Invoked the function and it worked fine.

Comment: The first if statement will always be true even if the user holds down the altKey, so the else if block is never reached, the altKey logic should be handled inside the e.keyCode === 13 if logic..

Comment: Yeah..You are right.I just checked Why the "submit on Enter" thing is not working.Should have gone deeper..